# Add timezone into current time stamp for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, datetime

I am using the following code and it returns:

```
now = time.strftime("%c")
Out[196]: 
'Mon Jan  9 18:34:48 2017'
```

We have some parsers that read the timestamps, and they expect the following convention:

```
Mon Jan  9 17:02:40 PST 2017
```

The main difference is between the seconds and the year my code is missing the timezone. I have played around with the `time.strftime` and `datetime` libraries, however I'm still not able to get the alignment of the timestamp I'm looking for.

I also thought I could insert or join the timestamp into my existing string that was missing the timezone, however even that was not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the timezone using `datetime` instead of `time`:

```
import datetime as dt
from tzlocal import get_localzone  # $ pip install tzlocal
local_tz = get_localzone()

now = dt.datetime.now(local_tz)
print now.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
```

Be sure to assign a timezone to the `datetime` as [naive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) timestamps will not display a timezone.

The above produces:

```
Mon Jan 09 19:40:28 PST 2017
```